# How to pass informations trough (or before) header location

Tags: php, prestashop

I have complex problem.
I'm using jquery tabs on my Prestashop module. I have following tabs on my plugin page:

[image]

Inside every tab I have inputs for my plugin and save button. If I'm on e.g `Footer` and I will click my save button then page refreshes, save changes and then I'm in my first tab (`General`) instead of `Footer`.
I found solution for this. After every SAVE I'm using

`return header("Location: ".$moduledir.'#'.$tab);`

where `$tab = 'tabname'` and `$moduledir = plugin url`. Header location protects me before re-submitting the form after F5 page refresh. But it's also not effective because I'm also need to pass some informations after save e.g 'Configuration updated' or some error.

```
public function Output($tab,$outputmessage=null)
{
    $moduledir = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?controller=AdminModules&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules').'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;

    if ($tab == null)
    {
        return $this->RenderConfig(); # This method displays my plugin
    }
    else
    {
      # I don't know how to also pass by header location my
      # $outputmessage variable which contains
      # information to display. Normally I would use
      # return $outputmessage.$this->RenderConfig();
      # but then it's always brings me to tab general
      return header("Location: ".$moduledir.'#'.$tab);
    }
}
```

I know that probably there is a better way to do this but I don't know how.
Please guys, give me some tips because I'm stupid right now and have no idea how to solve this.

**// EDIT**

I think I found solution but for now I'm not 100% sure.

```
public function Output($tab,$display=null)
{
    $tab = '<script>parent.location.hash = "'.$tab.'";</script>';
    return $tab.$display.$this->RenderConfig();
}
```

Comment: Don't pass back the header function. Pass back the page it should go to then after using the save send the header with the returned page to redirect the user to. For example `return $moduledir.'#'.$tab;`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm going to test your idea.

Comment: Return a JSON object with informations and use javascript to use the informations and redirection to the new page.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Why javascript? Doesn't appear the OP is outputting any content to the browser, just executing the header to early in the process.

Comment: @chris85 If he returns a redirect header the body response doesn't matter to the browser. The user gets directly redirected and doesn't see the body response. Well I thought he uses AJAX. But that's a misunderstanding. He should use the HTML meta tag redirection then.

Comment: @chris85 Please provide me a bit more code details. I'm not entirely sure how to do it and when should I redirect page because If I first return page with `$outputmessage` and then use `header location` my `$outputmessage` will disappear after this redirect.

Comment: If you're outputting to the browser you can't do that with the `header` you'll need @CharlotteDunois solution to do the redirect client side in that instance. I thought you were doing all PHP processing.

Comment: I think that returning all informations in json object isn't quite good idea. My plugin is located inside prestashop backoffice page... So, I think I should return a normal page content via PHP with JSON object 
which will contain only `tab name` and then with javascript do some magic?

Comment: I think I found solution but I'm not sure for now. I've updated my answer.